# Adding hosted service seems to crash Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

So I have a webservice running in an Azure WebApp, that is the backend for a Blazor frontend. It has api controllers and SignalR.

For easier local development, I added a hosted service using `.AddHostedService` to have a small shell in the console for querying or triggering things without having to go through swagger or the frontend. This shell is a BackgroundService with practically this:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    this.Looper = Task.Run(() => Loop(stoppingToken), stoppingToken);
    return this.Looper;
}


private async void Loop(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    char chosenOption;
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && (chosenOption = GetChoice()) != 'Q')
    {
        await Commands[Commands.Keys.Single(key => key[0] == chosenOption)]();
    }
}

private char GetChoice()
{
    char chosenOption;
    Console.WriteLine("Menu:");
    do
    {
        foreach (var choice in Choices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(choice);
        }

        chosenOption = char.ToUpper(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
        Console.WriteLine();
    } while (!IsValidChoice(chosenOption));

    return chosenOption;
}
```

But for some reason, the Azure WebApp now crashes on startup.
Can an Azure WebApp just not handle a hosted service or shell? Because it works fine in the local self-hosted application.

Comment: Did you check kudu console to get what your application writes before crash?

Comment: I did not, and that is exactly what I need! Will try to find the kudu console.

Comment: So I guess in kudu, the logstream is what I want? I can't open it, it says text/event-stream and can be open with no application.

Comment: Add details about kudu into your question and add a screenshot with kudu.

Comment: So I digged into kudu, took way too long to get some logs, for some reason now cannot download a logstream. I did however get redirected back to the azure portal and through that diagnostic tool found my actual error lol. Thanks for bringing me on this path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @mtkachenko I found the problem in the azure portal's diagnostic tools a few levels deep:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected`

Turns out `Console.ReadKey()` interacts directly with the console, not just with the input stream. As there is no console connected to the Azure WebApp though (instead the streams are redirected), it crashes trying to interact with the non-existing console.
`Console.Read` or `.ReadLine` will work though, as the streams are there.